# Finding the equation of the tangent(s) from a point OFF the curve.

Tags: calculus

I've been looking at over for this but I couldn't find it. If a question asks to find the equation of the tangent of a certain curve **at** a certain $x$ value, then I can do it, but not if the point if **off** the curve, then I get stuck.

Question: Find the equations of the tangents from the point $A(2,-2)$ to the ellipse with equation

$$x^2 + 4y^2 = 4$$

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough to get you started:

The equation of a straight line through $(2,-2)$ with gradient $m$ is

$$y+2 = m(x-2)$$

or

$$y = mx - 2m -2$$

You can use this in place of $y$ in the equation of the ellipse to get a quadratic in x which give the points of intersection of the line and the ellipse (if there are any).

For the line to be a tangent, you need the quadratic to have a double root, so use the standard test for a double root to get a condition on $m$ ...

Answer (score 0):

## Hint:

It is a straight line passing through $(2,-2)$ and has slope $m$ and so the equation is
$$y+2=m(x-2)\implies y=mx-2m-2 $$Suppose that it touches the curve at $(a,b)$ then
$$\color{red}{b=ma-2m-2}\ \ \ and \ \ \color{red}{a^2+4b^2=4}$$Finally the slope equal the first derivative
$$2x+8yy'=0\implies x+4yy'=0\implies\\ \color{red}{a+4bm=0}$$Solve the three red equations for $m$